# How to get the variable value from child to parent in ssis 2008?

Tags: ssis

In my scenario updating table value which is passing from child to parent.
I am using EPT(Execute package task) to call the child package and in one of variable value in child package will be updated in the parent package. So I am using parent package configuration but value is not populated in parent package level.

In both child and parent package level the variable name should be same in my case.

Please help out me on this scenario.

Regards,
Ravi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating variables in child and master pacakge , use master package variable in child as read variable and assign values to that variables. then after executing the child came back to master that variables are updated with child values.I tried and sucseeded.

Thanks Ravikumar

Comment: Damn, it really works. What an ugly hack :D But extremely useful though! Thanks, man.

Answer (score 2):

We can assign Child variable value to parent variable only at run time.
As parent pakage acts as a container for child pakage so parent variable can be accessed but only at run time.

This can be achevied using script task in child pakage.

Below are the steps:-

1- Create a variable in parent pakage. 
2- Create a child variable in child pakage.
3- Open script task in child pakage.
4-Assign ReadOnlyVariables variable option as child variable.
5 Assign ReadWriteVariables variable option as parent variable.

(** Note :- Parent variable will not be available in ReadWriteVariables variable option but dnt worry just give the name manually example:- "User::ParentVariable"

**"This works because the script task doesn't validate the variable names declared in its ReadOnlyVariables & ReadWriteVariables properties at design-time."**
)

6-  Edit the script task and use the below code to assign child variable value to parent variable.

```
 public void Main()

{
  Dts.Variables["Parentvariable"].Value=Dts.Variables["Childvariable"].Value.ToString();

}
```

Hope it helped...Thanks  :) !!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that setting of variables in a child package using Parent Package configurations is like passing a variable to a function by value rather than by reference.  In other words, you are setting the value of the child variable at execution time to the value of the variable in the parent package.  As these two items are separate executables, the scope of the variables cannot (up through 2008 at least) pass up to a parent from the child.  You will need to look at storing the data in some other location (store it into a table perhaps) and retrieve it from that location after the control returns to the parent package.  I believe you may have a higher level of scoped variables in 2012, but I have not yet moved any packages to that level yet, so I would have to defer in that are to those who may have used 2012.

Comment: Instead of creating variables in child and master pacakge , use master package variable in child as read variable and assign values to that variables. then after executing the child came back to master that variables are updated with child values.I tried and sucseeded.Thanks Ravikumar.